# Passing arguments for different functions into an R function

Tags: r, rlang

I have a “master” function `foo` from which I need to call two other functions `fun1` and `fun2`. Each of these has separate argument sets which I'd like to set from outside.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang

fun1 <- function(a, c) {
  print(glue::glue("a is {a}"))
  print(glue::glue("c is {c}"))
}

fun2 <- function(e, g) {
  print(glue::glue("e is {e}"))
  print(glue::glue("g is {g}"))
}

foo <- function(something, additional_args) {
  print(glue::glue("Called with {something}"))
  # I know I can do this, but I don't want to explicitly specify a, c, e and g here!)
  fun1(additional_args$fun1_args$a, additional_args$fun1_args$c)
  fun2(additional_args$fun2_args$e, additional_args$fun2_args$g)
}

foo("something", additional_args = list(
  fun1_args = list(a = "b", c = "d"),
  fun2_args = list(e = "f", g = "h")
))
#> Called with something
#> a is b
#> b is d
#> c is f
#> d is h
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Obviously, it's not very nice that I have to repeat the names of the arguments inside `foo`. And the functions `fun1` and `fun2` may take many more arguments, or not all of them, or have some defaults.

I don't think I've fully grasped quasiquotation. And I read through [the documentation](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/multiple.html), but nothing there applies. I am not using `...` anywhere since I don't want to mix up arguments for function `fun1` and `fun2`.

How can I replace these weird calls, in which I explicitly specify the arguments, so that they just forward the arguments instead?

```r
  fun1(additional_args$fun1_args$a, additional_args$fun1_args$c)
  fun2(additional_args$fun2_args$e, additional_args$fun2_args$g)
```

I have tried

```r
  fun1_args = enquos(additional_args$fun1_args)
  fun1(!!! fun1_args)
```

But it says:

> Error: Inputs to capture must be argument names

I've also tried `fun1(!!!additional_args$fun1_args)`, but it says:

> Error in !additional_args$fun1_args : invalid argument type

Comment: `do.call(fun1, additional_args$fun1_args)`. Also note that you define the additional_args incorrectly, providing arguments 'a' and 'c' for function `fun1`, while `fun1` is supposed to take 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: That works, thanks. If I want to add another parameter, I have to run `do.call(fun1, append(additional_args$fun1_args, list(another_parameter = "test")))` … would you like to provide a full answer?

Comment: And thanks for the info, I fixed the code. Quite apparently, it never executed that far.

Comment: No need for a full answer. `append` works, but so does `c(additional_args$fun1_args, another_parameter="test")`, which is shorter.

Comment: Well, if there were an answer, the question could be marked as solved. If you don't want to provide one, I can write one up though.

Comment: No you can't, someone marked it as a duplicate ;-)

Comment: Eh, of course. Good duplicate question – wasn't able to find that when I was searching.